# iOS Autolayout : Dynamically adjust controls

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, xcode5, autolayout

I am practicing autolayout, I have struck on some issue, My layout is like

```
== Username TextField ==
== Password Textfield ==
==Login Button ==
```

But when user enters wrong username or password it should be changed to

```
== Username TextField ==
== Password Textfield ==
== Verification Textfield == 
==Login Button ==
```

I know how to achieve it by setting frames but I want to do it by autolayout and constrains
So I need your help to do it. And it would be great if I can do it using storyboard without writing single line of code

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The desire layout is simple and possible to get done with the help of autolayout but you question is not specific about any problem but in general so i would suggest take a look here a great tutorials about autolayout http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1 and try to understand the basic concept, and if you have any specific trouble then you are welcome

Comment: Sure :) but this link is just to clear the idea how to get what you want